# RSA Encryption Original Primes $p$ and $q$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, computer-science, prime-factorization

I am well aware of the math behind the RSA encryption system, and why it works. The bank, for example, publishes a pair of numbers $(e,n)$ which are used for encryption by the customers. The bank then changes the number $e$ to $d$ and uses the pair $(d,n)$ to decrypt the message. Only a person with the number $d$ could decrypt the message, and only the bank has it, as it only published the numbers $e$ and $n$ - NOT $d$. I won't go into details about why and how it works - not because it's difficult but because it's a long explanation.

But anyways, the math behind this deal states that $$d = \frac{2\cdot\phi(n)+1}{e}$$
Now, we said that $e$ and $n$ are given, then what's the problem decrypting the message? One could easily find $d$, right? NO. $e$ is simple enough to insert into the above, but calculating $\phi(n)$ becomes a very difficult task given that $n$ is sufficiently large, because factorizing an integer is a difficult task. It's been found by Euler that $$\phi(n) = n\cdot\prod_{p|n}(1-\frac1p)$$ where the product runs over the prime factors of $n$.

Now, given $n=p\cdot q$ and $p$ and $q$ are prime, we get that $$\phi(n)=(p-1)\cdot (q-1)$$ So what the bank does, is they choose $n$ such that it will be large and difficult to factorize, and people won't be able to find the prime factors of $n$, rendering them unable to find $d$ and decrypt message, passwords, and break into others' bank accounts. They choose $n$ to be semiprime (multiplication of just 2 prime numbers) becaue it's the most difficult to factorize. I understand that the modern technology doesn't allow these $n$ to be easily factorized, but my question, given that the bank has more or less the same technology as other high-tech companies, is how does the bank itself come up with these semiprimes $n$ and primes $p$ and $q$ from the first place? Some $n$ are 600+ digits long, which makes $p$ and $q$ already difficult enough to be proven prime (certain primality tests for 300+ digits' numbers). So how do banks and other companies such as google, twitter, facebook and others come up with these numbers?

**How is it that they themselves are able to find such numbers which they claim will take modern computers thousands of years to factorize?**

Comment: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can just be done by trial and error, because large-ish primes (say with 200 digits or more) aren't really that rare. About 1 in $\frac{1}{\log N}$ numbers near $N$ are prime. For $N = 10^{100}$, about one in 230 integers this number are prime. Since you know that even numbers or numbers ending in 5 aren't prime, you have to test 100 numbers on average to find a 100 digit prime.

The second ingredient is that testing whether a number is prime can be done very quickly, unlike actual factoring, using [primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) such as the Miller-Rabin test.

For example. the smallest prime number with 100 digits is $10^{99} + 289$. The next one is $10^{99} + 303$. The one after that is $10^{99} + 711$. The one after that is larger than $10^{99} + 999$. That's three primes in an interval of length 1000, which is reasonable close to 1 in 230.

Answer (score 3):

Primality tests run in polynomial or subpolynomial runtime as compared to the exponential runtime of current factoring algorithms. Most RSA implementations use the [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test), which runs *very* quickly with a good implementation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336642/what-are-typical-runtimes-for-miller-rabin-primality-testing) quotes a 0.65 ms runtime for a 400 digit prime with desktop hardware, which is more than fast enough to be practical.